# awk sum collect in groups

Tags: awk, ksh

question is for awk script (ref previous question some weeks ago) but bit more complicated .

input file looks :

```
Group1
id        val1     val2
---------------------------
idone      2        10
idone      3        12
idone      6         9
idtwo      8         3
idtwo     14         1

Subtotal  33        35


Group2
id        val1     val2 
------------------------ 
idone     2         3
idone     1         4
idtwo     3         6
idtwo     4         7

Subtotal 10        20

Total    43        55
```

There might be more groups and in each group more entries .
I limited my example to 2 detail names idone,  idtwo and 2 groups.

Now the  purpose is to have them summarized.
with result as  :

```
          val1      val2

idone      14         38
idtwo      29         17

total      43         55
```

The output layout is free to choose : 
if you prefer it may look like this as well :

```
total_idone_val1=14
total_idone_val2=38  
total_idtwo_val1=29
total_idtwo_val2=17

overall_total_val1=43
overall_total_val2=55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this awk cmd a try:

```
 awk 'NF==3&&FNR>3&&!/[Tt]otal/{v1[$1]+=$2;v2[$1]+=$3}END{print "id","v1","v2";
                for(x in v1){
                print x,v1[x],v2[x]
                s1+=v1[x]
                s2+=v2[x]
        }
        print "total",s1,s2}' f1 f2
```

it gives:

```
id v1 v2
idtwo 29 17
idone 14 38
total 43 55
```